# Making image white space transparent, overlay onto imshow()

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a plot of spatial data  that I display with imshow().

I need to be able to overlay the crystal lattice that produced the data. I have a png
file of the lattice that loads as a black and white image.The parts of this image I want to
overlay are the black lines that are the lattice and not see the white background between the lines.

I'm thinking that I need to set the alphas for each background ( white ) pixel to transparent (0 ? ).

I'm so new to this that I don't really know how to ask this question.

EDIT:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

lattice = plt.imread('path')
im = plt.imshow(data[0,:,:],vmin=v_min,vmax=v_max,extent=(0,32,0,32),interpolation='nearest',cmap='jet')

im2 = plt.imshow(lattice,extent=(0,32,0,32),cmap='gray')

#thinking of making a mask for the white background
mask = np.ma.masked_where( lattice < 1,lattice ) #confusion here b/c even tho theimage is gray scale in8, 0-255, the numpy array lattice 0-1.0 floats...?
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show us an example (code)?  Also, see `set_under` and `set_bad` functions of `colormap`

Comment: Added some code ideas...and the lattice png. Perhaps I can use the np mask methods to identify the while bg pixels and set them to transparent.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With out your data, I can't test this, but something like

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import copy

my_cmap = copy.copy(plt.cm.get_cmap('gray')) # get a copy of the gray color map
my_cmap.set_bad(alpha=0) # set how the colormap handles 'bad' values
lattice = plt.imread('path')
im = plt.imshow(data[0,:,:],vmin=v_min,vmax=v_max,extent=(0,32,0,32),interpolation='nearest',cmap='jet')

lattice[lattice< thresh] = np.nan # insert 'bad' values into your lattice (the white)

im2 = plt.imshow(lattice,extent=(0,32,0,32),cmap=my_cmap)
```

Alternately, you can hand `imshow` a NxMx4 `np.array` of RBGA values, that way you don't have to muck with the color map

```
im2 = np.zeros(lattice.shape + (4,))
im2[:, :, 3] = lattice # assuming lattice is already a bool array

imshow(im2)
```

Comment: wow that works...thank you so much...I need to study this solution. Use of Nan's is clever...in my previous image processing experience Nan's would be cast into zeros...so I didn't consider them as a way to make pixels not drawn. The copy of the cm is interesting...I don't understand yet how matplotlib works...:( Cheers.

Comment: @wbg The copy is there so that you don't change the 'standard' gray color map, as `get_cmap` returns an object in a pre-populated array, rather than re-creating the colormap on the fly.

Comment: The doc for set_bad() was not very clear...now I see that by 'bad' they mean Nan, inf's and the like. I LOVE python and how elegant it is vs. MATLAB.  I'm still a bit bothered by the renormalized range 0-1 that imread() appears to invoke. I guess that allows for more generic use of color maps..? That's another thread I guess. Cheers to all.

Comment: @wbg, yes, the 0-1 range is an easy way to write code that can deal with all manner of images.  Most image types and be mapped to a float in that range with out losing any information, and now you have many less cases to deal with in the low-level code.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is to simply use your image as a background rather than an overlay.  Other than that you will need to use [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) or [Python Image Magic](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/api.php) bindings to convert the selected colour to transparent.

Don't forget you will probably also need to resize either your plot or your image so that they match in size.

### Update:

If you follow the tutorial [here](http://matplotlib.org/users/image_tutorial.html?highlight=image) with your image and then plot your data over it you should get what you need, note that the tutorial uses PIL so you will need that installed as well.