# How can i plot a figure above a contourf?

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour, figure, foreground

I would like to see a figure ABOVE a filled contour map. The code snippet below uses the matplotlib imshow method which leads to the figure being overlain by the contours - I would like to see it the other way around

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ax = F.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)  
plt.contourf(X, Y, Z, levels,
            linewidths=0.5,
            fontsize=9,
            cmap=cm.gist_rainbow,
            norm = normation,
            zorder=1
            #alpha=0.5
            )
im = plt.imread('background.png')
ax.imshow(im, extent=[0,4000,5500,0], zorder=10)
```

Comment: why not just do the contourf after the imshow? Also the contourf should probably be ax.contourf?

Comment: Adjusting the `zorder` kwarg should work.  The artist with the _higher_ `zorder` is drawn on top.

Comment: I could solve the problem myself after a journey through the web: 1. set image to a separate axis due to python problem with zorder and imshow [1]. 2. read data for image and set 'white' points opaque [2]. 3. mask the patch associated with the image [3]. <br/> [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16742111/scale-image-in-matplotlib-without-changing-the-axis <br/> [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18159874/making-image-white-space-transparent-overlay-onto-imshow <br/> [3]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16742111/scale-image-in-matplotlib-without-changing-the-axis