# Making figure transparent with colored background

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a bit of a situation. What I need is a plot with a black background with several white circles drawn on top of that black background.

I managed to do this using the following code:

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, aspect = "equal", axisbg = "black")
ax.add_artist(plt.Circle((0., 0., .5), color =   "white")) 

plt.xlim(-5, 5)
plt.ylim(-5, 5)

fig.savefig("test.png", dpi = 300)

plt.show()
```

This produces the following result:

[image]

Now, what I would like to do is make this image transparent. So what this means is that only the white circle should become transparent. You might already be able to see the problem arising because if I would set `transparent = True`. The black background automatically becomes transparent and I lose the colour black from my figure.

Another thing I tried is to not set `transparent = True` in `savefig` but to actually set the option `alpha = 0.` in `plt.Circle`. This makes the white circle actually transparent which is the end goal. However, because it is transparent I am left with an entire black background. Any ideas to solve this problem?

**To summarize my goal:**

I want to save a transparent version of the figure in which the white circle is transparent while the black parts are not.

I know I can use different programs such as `inkscape` and `gimp` to create what I want. However, I really need to do it within python as well due to other operations I need to perform.

Thank you!

Comment: Please reduce this to a minimal example.  As a physicist I like the picture, however I think you could demonstrate this problem with < 10 lines of code.  You will get better answers if you make it easy for the answers to understand what you are doing.

Comment: Much better (from a SO pov, I worked on jammed systems and their strange phonons in my PhD) and an interesting problem!  The way that AGG draws is that it puts down layers additatively which works well if you want to specify the positive of the image, but you are specifying the negative.  There are ways to get Agg to give you the RGBA buffer for the canvas and then you could fix this up and put it back on a canvas as an image, but that seems too round-about to be a good solution.

Comment: Thank you very much tcaswell for putting up the bounty. Without it I would probably still not have an answer.

Comment: Your welcome.  It looked like an interesting problem that should be solved.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18159874/making-image-white-space-transparent-overlay-onto-imshow/18167650#18167650 <- should have thought of this earlier

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit 3:

It has been clarified that the underlying question is:

how to put a 'black & transparent' mask in front of a matplotlib image produced by `imshow` ?
The mask shall result from a matplotlib previously drawn black & white figure.

The following code demonstrate this feature by accessing and mixing the figure rgba bitmaps:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab


def get_rgba_bitmap(fig):
    fig.canvas.draw()
    tab = fig.canvas.copy_from_bbox(fig.bbox).to_string_argb()
    ncols, nrows = fig.canvas.get_width_height()
    return np.fromstring(tab, dtype=np.uint8).reshape(nrows, ncols, 4)

def black_white_to_black_transpa(rgba):
    rgba[:, :, 3] = 255 - rgba[:, :, 0]
    rgba[:, :, 0:3] = 0

def over(rgba1, rgba2):
    if rgba1.shape != rgba2.shape:
        raise ValueError("rgba1 and rgba2 shall have same size")
    alpha = np.expand_dims(rgba1[:, :, 3] / 255., 3)
    rgba =  np.array(rgba1 * alpha + rgba2 * (1.-alpha), dtype = np.uint8)
    return rgba[:, :, 0:3]


# fig 1)
fig1 = plt.figure(facecolor = "white")
fig1.set_dpi(300)
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, aspect = "equal", axisbg = "black")
ax1.add_artist(plt.Circle((0., 0., .5), color =   "white")) 
ax1.set_xlim(-5, 5)
ax1.set_ylim(-5, 5)
bitmap_rgba1 = get_rgba_bitmap(fig1)
black_white_to_black_transpa(bitmap_rgba1)

# fig 2
fig2 = plt.figure(facecolor = "white")
fig2.set_dpi(300)
delta = 0.025
ax2 = fig2.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, aspect = "equal", axisbg = "black")
ax2.set_xlim(-5, 5)
ax2.set_ylim(-5, 5)
x = y = np.arange(-3.0, 3.0, delta)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z1 = mlab.bivariate_normal(X, Y, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
Z2 = mlab.bivariate_normal(X, Y, 1.5, 0.5, 1, 1)
Z = Z2-Z1  # difference of Gaussians
im = ax2.imshow(Z, interpolation='bilinear', cmap=cm.jet,
                origin='lower', extent=[-5, 5, -5, 5],
                vmax=abs(Z).max(), vmin=-abs(Z).max())
bitmap_rgba2 = get_rgba_bitmap(fig2)    

# now saving the composed figure 
fig = plt.figure()
fig.patch.set_alpha(0.0) 
ax = fig.add_axes([0., 0., 1., 1.])
ax.patch.set_alpha(0.0) 
ax.imshow(over(bitmap_rgba1, bitmap_rgba2))
plt.axis('off')
fig.savefig("test_transpa.png", dpi=300)

plt.show()
```

Giving:
[image]

I tested with your initial photonic test case and the pic quality seems OK

[image]

Now if you want the figure background transparent too:

- Set fig1 background to 'white' i.e. `fig1 = plt.figure(facecolor='white')`, as white will become transparent when passed to `black_white_to_black_transpa`
- Set fig2 background to transparent `fig2.patch.set_alpha(0.0)` as it will be stored with no modification into `bitmap_rgba2`
- Finally, take care of the alpha channel when mixing `bitmap_rgba1` and `bitmap_rgba2` inside `over` function (see below a possible modification)

> ```
> def over(rgba1, rgba2):
>     if rgba1.shape != rgba2.shape:
>         raise ValueError("rgba1 and rgba2 shall have same size")
>     alpha1 = np.expand_dims(rgba1[:, :, 3] / 255., axis=3)
>     alpha2 = np.expand_dims(rgba2[:, :, 3] / 255., axis=3)
>     alpha = 1. - (1.-alpha1) * (1.-alpha2)
>     C1 = rgba1[:, :, 0:3]
>     C2 = rgba2[:, :, 0:3]
>     C = (alpha1 * C1 + (1-alpha1) * alpha2 * C2) / alpha
>     rgba =  np.empty_like(rgba1, dtype = np.uint8)
>     rgba[:, :, 0:3] = C
>     rgba[:, :, 3] = 255 * alpha[:, :, 0]
>     return rgba
> ```

**last (?) edit:**
It seems there is an inconsistence between the array returned by`to_string_argb` and the one expected by `imshow` (order of the rgb channels). A possible solution is to change `ax.imshow(over(bitmap_rgba1, bitmap_rgba2))` to:

```
over_tab = over(bitmap_rgba1, bitmap_rgba2)
over_tab[:, :, 0:3] = over_tab[:, :, ::-1][:, :, 1:4]
ax.imshow(over_tab)
```

Comment: This is going in the right direction. Two questions remain: 1) Is there a way to increase the resolution of the resulting bitmap_rgba? 2) I have two figures now, the bitmap_rgba and another image obtained using imshow. I need to overlap the two in the same figure window. How can I do this with the bitmap_rgba? Tried using zorder but does not help

Comment: 1) You should call `fig.set_dpi(300)` on the first figure, before calling `get_rgba_bitmap`. See http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html?highlight=set_dpi#matplotlib.figure.Figure.set_dpi

Comment: 2) An idea is to create 2 `bitmap_rgba` arrays of same dimension  for your 2 figures and combine them manually. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing

Comment: This is exactly as I would like it to be and it works like a charm. Thank you very much!

Comment: I still have a small question. I've been playing around with `facecolor = 'white'` but I can not get my white background to be transparent. The white background is similar to your grey background in your final image.

Comment: Your `get_rgba_bitmap(fig)` functions inverts the `cmap` of `imshow`. How can I prevent/correct for this? I'm using a colormap I created myself. Inverting this one before creating the bitmap is not an option.

Comment: Indeed. I had not noticed this and I am a bit surprised (I am unsure if it is the expected behaviour, I have to read again the doc). Would you mind trying the code added in my edit ?

Comment: Your solution works although I still find it very weird that it already inverts the `cmap` at `get_rgba_bitmap`. I know that you basically only want the canvas in this case when overlapping the two types of figures I have. However it feels a bit weird to correct for the `cmap` after `get_rgba_bitmap`.

Comment: Note that technically this is not an inversion of the colormap but rather of the red and blue channels. You can check by setting another colormap, for instance `cmap=cm.reds`. It could be a bug in `to_string_argb` but I am not fully sure.

Answer (score 1):

## Circles masked with colorbar

Colormaps can have an alpha channel, so if your data is on a mesh with high vs low values showing circle vs not-circle, one set of those values can be transparent.

This only works for me when saving the figure programmatically, with the `transparent` keyword; not from the Python image window.

Starting from one of the matplotlib gallery examples (in a gimp-alike, I can cut & paste segments and the transparency is right):

```
# plot transparent circles with a black background
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap
from matplotlib.cm import Greys


dark_low = ((0., 1., 1.),
         (.3, 1., 0.),
         (1., 0., 0.))
         
cdict = {'red':  dark_low,

     'green': dark_low,

     'blue': dark_low}

cdict3 = {'red':  dark_low,

     'green': dark_low,

     'blue': dark_low,
               
     'alpha': ((0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
               (0.3, 0.0, 1.0),
               (1.0, 1.0, 1.0))
    }

greys = LinearSegmentedColormap('Greys', cdict)
plt.register_cmap(cmap=greys)
    
dropout_high = LinearSegmentedColormap('Dropout', cdict3)
plt.register_cmap(cmap = dropout_high)

# Make some illustrative fake data:

x = np.arange(0, np.pi, 0.1)
y = np.arange(0, 2*np.pi, 0.1)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
Z = np.cos(X) * np.sin(Y) * 10

# Make the figure:

plt.figure()
plt.subplot(1,3,1)
plt.imshow(Z, cmap=Greys)
plt.title('Smooth\ncolorbar')
plt.colorbar()
plt.subplot(1,3,2)
plt.imshow(Z, cmap=greys)
plt.title('Linear\ncolorbar')
plt.colorbar()
plt.subplot(1,3,3)
plt.imshow(Z, cmap = dropout_high)
plt.title('Alpha crops\n colorbar')
plt.colorbar()
plt.savefig('dropout_cmap', transparent=True)
```

[image: Adapting colorbar to a alpha-channel visual mask]

And as a layer over another image. Interesting, the colorbar with alpha channel *doesn't* have transparency. That seems like a bug.

[image: Plots with and without alpha-channel over another image]

Comment: Do you in fact want the image-with-transparency to frisket over another image, @TheDude? I didn't see the original state of the question, but there's a reference somewhere to needing a whole lot of the transparent circles.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the answer you are looking for but it gives the picture you wanted! I think you want to fill the areas outside the circle!(s) with black and leave the background transparent, rather than the other way around. It's trivial to calculate the boundaries of a single circle and use `fill_between`. Doing it for multiple circles might be trickier!

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, aspect = "equal", )

# A Circle
xy=(1,1); r=3

# more points is smoother
xdata=np.linspace(-5,5,1001)
ydata=np.linspace(-5,5,1001)

# circle edges (top and bottom)
c1=np.sqrt((xy[0]**2-xdata**2)+r**2)+xy[1]
c2=-np.sqrt((xy[0]**2-xdata**2)+r**2)+xy[1]

c1=np.where(np.isnan(c1),xy[0],c1)
c2=np.where(np.isnan(c2),xy[0],c2)

ax.fill_between(xdata,5,c1,color='black')
ax.fill_between(xdata,-5,c2,color='black')

plt.xlim(-5, 5)
plt.ylim(-5, 5)

fig.savefig("test.png", dpi = 300, transparent=True)
```

[Transparent circle with center 1,1 and radius 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wx2T3.png)

Comment: The question got simplified too much, the application the OP wants is to put down ~1k circles to make photonic crystals (see the edit history).

Comment: OK, I can see that my solution won't work for the application. Any reason not to use `os.system("convert test.png -transparent white image_transparent.png")` at the end of the script in the question? I know it's not a matplotlib solution, but it's an easy one.

Comment: It might be good enough for the OP, but I am looking for a pure mpl solution ;)

Comment: Fair enough. But I think that plotting circles over a black background is not the way to approach this, somehow filling the gaps between the circles would be a solution. Would it be worth my while writing up a solution identifying which parts of a 1000x1000 grid were *not* within a circle and using `pcolormesh` to fill them?

Comment: If you wanted to do it that way, you should just grab the RGBA buffer from AGG (it will do the figuring of what pixels are/arn't in a circle much faster) and then render that array back to a new canvas.