# Create canvas of plotting frame

Tags: python, canvas, matplotlib

I have the following function:

```
def get_rgba_bitmap(fig):
  fig.canvas.draw()
  tab = fig.canvas.copy_from_bbox(fig.bbox).to_string_argb()
  ncols, nrows = fig.canvas.get_width_height()
  return numpy.fromstring(tab, dtype = numpy.uint8).reshape(nrows, ncols, 4)
```

With this function I am able to create a "map" of an image. See [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23684928/making-figure-transparent-with-colored-background) for more details on why I need the "map" and the answer resulting in the function. Plotting the "map" gives:

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

random_gen = numpy.random.mtrand.RandomState(seed = 127260)
x_test = random_gen.uniform(-1., 1., size= (10,10))

fig1 = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax1.imshow(x_test, cmap = "seismic")

bitmap_rgba1 = get_rgba_bitmap(fig1)

fig2 = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig2.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax1.imshow(bitmap_rgba1)

plt.show()
```

[image]

The canvas that is created with `get_rgba_bitmap(fig)` is of the entire figure including the grey background. When plotting the "map", the grey background is thus also included, shrinking the size of the actual image. In the case of a single image this does not matter to me as there is a way to work around it. However, I now need several subplots and it does become a problem.

Therefore, what I now need is a function that creates a canvas of only the plotting frame. Ticks and labels are not important. I tried modifying the `get_rgba_bitmap` function but it does not fully work:

```
def test(fig, ax):
  fig.canvas.draw()
  tab = fig.canvas.copy_from_bbox(ax.bbox).to_string_argb()

  bbox = ax.get_window_extent().transformed(fig.dpi_scale_trans.inverted())
  width, height = bbox.width * fig.dpi, bbox.height * fig.dpi

  ncols, nrows = width, height
  return numpy.fromstring(tab, dtype = numpy.uint8).reshape(nrows + 1, ncols + 1, 4)
```

I think the problem lies in wrong values for `ncols` and `nrows`. Not sure where this comes from.

If I add 1 to both `ncols` and `nrows` in `reshape`, the script runs and produces an image close to what I want. However, the "map" does not fit correctly in the new plotting frame, which from the look of it is off by 1 pixel in `x` and `y`. This corresponds to the 1 I needed to add to `nrows` and `ncols`. How can I fix this?

[image]

Thank you for help

Comment: Could you please make the figure reproductible by setting the same seed ? Something like `random_gen = np.random.mtrand.RandomState(seed=127260)` and then `x_test = random_gen.uniform(-1., 1., size=n_test)`

Comment: The seed is set. I'm also confident the offset in `x` and `y` is due to the 1 I needed to add to get the correct array size (`nrows` * `ncols` * 4). What I basically need to achieve is an array size of `nrows` * `ncols` * 4, where `nrows` and `ncols` are defined as I did in the function above. However, this needs to be done without data loss.

Comment: Would `ax1.imshow(bitmap_rgba1[:-1, 1:])` help in solving your issue ?

Comment: Again, this does the trick. You have been a great help! Do you have a link to the documentation that you used? I have been searching for one but I always seem to end up at Tkinter Widgets.

Comment: This question was very helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21939658/matplotlib-render-into-buffer-access-pixel-data. However I also had to read the source code as these features seems not very deeply documented.