# How to fade color to transparent using hexbin and matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am creating a "heatmap" using hexbin, and want this heatmap to be placed on top of an image. However, I would like to have the coloring of the plot fade to transparent as the frequency does (i.e. as the color fades to white, it disappears). I have tried changing the alpha value but that does not produce the desired effect.

My code is:

```
n = 100000
x = np.random.standard_normal(n)
img = imread("soccer.jpg")
y = 2.0 + 3.0 * x + 4.0 * np.random.standard_normal(n)
plt.hexbin(x,y, bins='log', cmap=plt.cm.Reds, alpha = 0.3)
plt.imshow(img,zorder=0, extent=[-10, 10, -20, 20])
#plt.show()
plt.savefig('map.png')
```

I am open to using a 2d-histogram or any other plotting function. Even just being transparent when there are no values in that hexagon would be great, as many of my areas have zero data points.

The image produced by my current code is:

[image: Heatmap image]

Comment: Have you tried using a colormap that uses the alpha channel? I can't think of a built-in one, but I made one for [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23684928/making-figure-transparent-with-colored-background/23798831#23798831). That is, I would try a colormap that plots small values to some color with low alpha and higher values to distinctive colors, with high alpha.

Comment: That sounds like the kind of answer I was looking for, but I don't know much about the color schemes. I will definitely give this a try. Thanks!

Comment: The colormap from that example would be the one I call `dropout_high`, except you probably want to drop-out the low values. You'll edit the alpha section of the dictionary it's made from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rough example to be going on with:

```
n = 100000
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap


x = np.random.standard_normal(n)
img = plt.imread("soccer.jpg")
y = 2.0 + 3.0 * x + 4.0 * np.random.standard_normal(n)

red_high = ((0., 0., 0.),
         (.3, .5, 0.5),
         (1., 1., 1.))

blue_middle = ((0., .2, .2),
         (.3, .5, .5),
         (.8, .2, .2),
         (1., .1, .1))

green_none = ((0,0,0),(1,0,0))

cdict3 = {'red':  red_high,

     'green': green_none,

     'blue': blue_middle,

     'alpha': ((0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
               (0.3, 0.5, 0.5),
               (1.0, 1.0, 1.0))
    }


dropout_high = LinearSegmentedColormap('Dropout', cdict3)
plt.register_cmap(cmap = dropout_high)

plt.hexbin(x,y, bins='log', cmap=dropout_high)
plt.imshow(img,zorder=0, extent=[-10, 10, -20, 20])
plt.show()
#plt.savefig('map.png')
```

[image]

(I'm afraid my soccer field is sideways. I usually play as though it is, so.)